# Displaying photos from a selected directory

Tags: c#, xaml, photo-gallery

I'm working on an image gallery as a small project to learn how to program, what I'm trying to get now is to select a directory and all images will be displayed. This is what I have now

**.xaml**

```
<Grid x:Name="gridGallery" Height="610.667" Margin="205,70,0,0" Width="1058.338">
     <ListBox x:Name="listBoxGallery">
          <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                         <Image Margin="5" Source="{Binding Path}" Height="150" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                         <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
               </DataTemplate>
          </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

**.xaml.cs**

```
private void ButtonDirectory_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     var dialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog
     {
          DefaultDirectory = "Photos",
          IsFolderPicker = true
     };
     if (dialog.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
     {
          //adds all photos in the selected folder to gallery
     }
}
```

I don't know if I'm doing anything wrong and don't know what to add after I select the directory, any help would be awesome.

Comment: It is unclear from your code exactly what is not happening which you think should be happening. What guidance are you exactly seeking?

Comment: Check this link it may help:
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1237443/Csharp-how-to-sort-images-next-to-each-other-WPF-o